# Using FindStr + length in batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

In my text file is this line.

```
08.01.2013 20:06:36: SolsticeFTW (109.189.238.113:60381) 04ee8dfa81f700bba194a528911ecb4a - #0
08.01.2013 20:11:00: SolsticeFTW (109.189.238.113:60381) 04ee8dfa81f700bba194a528911ecb4a - #0
08.01.2013 20:11:24: SolsticeFTW (109.189.238.113:60381) 04ee8dfa81f700bba194a528911ecb4a - #0
08.01.2013 20:11:50: SolsticeFTW (109.189.238.113:60381) 04ee8dfa81f700bba194a528911ecb4a - #0
09.01.2013 15:39:57: lalka (95.165.55.92:15609) 161c5a17c5afc0b1e079fca7fdc8f1a9 - #0
```

I want to Filter a text file per the Command Findstr, this works but I cant get it to work that only filters the 32 digit word. For example 04ee8dfa81f700bba194a528911ecb4a and 161c5a17c5afc0b1e079fca7fdc8f1a9. It only works so far by filtering the complete line.

Does anyone know how i am able to filter just the 32 digit symbols/token?

Answer (score 1):

FINDSTR can only print the entire line that matches. It does not have the capability of something like grep that can list only the matching portion of the text.

The FOR /F command can often be used to extract tokens from a line of text, depending on the format of the data. You could use FINDSTR to select only the appropriate lines, and FOR /F to process those results and extract the 32 digit token.

I don't know what your FINDSTR search criteria is, so I'll make something up for use as an example. Suppose you want to print out the 32 digit token for lines that end with `#0`.

FINDSTR selects the appropriate lines, looking for lines that end with `#0`. And FOR /F parses each resultant line into tokens, delimited by spaces. (The token delimiter can be changed via the DELIMS option, but it is space and tab by default). You want the 5th token.

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%A in ('findstr /le " #0" "someFile.txt"') do echo %%A
```

**Edit in response to OP comment**

If you don't need to filter the lines and you simply want to write each 32 digit ID to a new file, then it is even simpler:

```
(for /f "tokens=5" %%A in (logged-players.log) do echo %%A) >logged-bans.txt
```

Comment: The Textbox above is called "logged-players.log".

I want just the 32 Digit Tokens/ID's written into a textfile called "logged-bans.txt".

Just the ID not the #0 or anything just the Token/ID with 32 digits.

Using [0-9a-z] may work but i dont know with which command.

Comment: then i get "C:\Test>echo 161c5a17c5afc0b1e079fca7fdc8f1a9 
161c5a17c5afc0b1e079fca7fdc8f1a9" but i want just the " 161c5a17c5afc0b1e079fca7fdc8f1a9" to show up not the path and echo..

Comment: @user1984532 - Turn `ECHO OFF`, or else put an `@` in front of the command, as in `do @echo %%A`.