# Windows Batch Regex Issue (Match not found)

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

This is a simple batch file that should run through a file (PingList_Results.txt) and pull out any line that matches the regex (IPv4 Addy) but it isn't working. I'm sure the issue is simple but I don't see it. Thanks!

Sample PingList_Results.txt:

> Pinging 10.10.10.11 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 10.10.10.11:
>   bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=54
>
> Ping statistics for 10.10.10.11:
>       Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 62ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 62ms
>
> Pinging 192.168.1.50  with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 192.168.1.50:
>   bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=120
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.1.50:
>       Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 61ms, Maximum = 61ms, Average = 61ms

**Batch File:**

```
@echo off

SET LOGFILE=PingList_Results.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /R "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" %LOGFILE%') DO (ECHO.%%A)
```

Comment: _but it isn't working_ isn't very specific. What you get and what do you expect?

Comment: It returns nothing. I was expecting a match to be returned. If I remove the {1,3} it does match but instead of returning the match, it returns the whole line.

Comment: You could read [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/463115) for the most exact description of `findstr`

Comment: A helper batch file called `repl.bat` will give you better regexp and without the many bugs of `findstr`.  It uses built in WSH features of Windows -  You can get it from here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINDSTR doesn't have {#,#} support, instead it is trying to match those characters literally - try the following instead:

```
@echo off

SET LOGFILE=PingList_Results.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('FINDSTR /R "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" %LOGFILE% ') DO (ECHO %%A)
```

This effectively does the same thing, but doesn't require {1,3} where [0-9]* represents *zero* or more matches.

Sourced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994395/how-to-match-ip-address-by-using-findstr-or-any-other-method-of-batch-in-wind).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. I was just wanting the further validation so 1234.1.1.1 would NOT match. It's cool though, this will get the simple job done.

Answer (score 0):

see: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

so far I have this:

FINDSTR /R "([0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*)" %LOGFILE%

But I can't figure out how to just output the found text.

I don't think {1,3} is supported in findstr.

Comment: You're right, it appears to not take {1,3}. It also returns the entire line instead of just the match...

Comment: From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363981/using-findstr-length-in-batch  it seems findstr doesn't support doing just the match.  You are probably going to want to use something else.  Sad, because findstr is built in.